# mediaplayer unknown does not play sound on some one device

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, device

I am using a mediaplayer object to play an `.amr` sound file. Now everything  on emulators and all devices that I tested the app (5 devices total) are OK. The problem is  when I try to test the app on a huawei p8 lite , I get a `media_unknown_error`.

I have already tried checking if the mediaplayer is not prepared before playing or the devices volume level is low, but it seems the problem is something else .

here is my errors

```
I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake true uid: 10110, pid: 31906
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1010)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1010)
I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10110, pid: 31906
```

Comment: please post your code of mediaplayer

Comment: changed the file format from .amr to .acc it plays on all devices now

Comment: why down vote ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
package com.example.com.mak.mediaplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer mpp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.red); //amr file in res/raw folder

    Button btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnplay); //Play
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View vone) {
        mpp.start();
      }
    });

    Button btnpause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnpause); //Pause
    btnpause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View vtwo) {
        if (mpp.isPlaying()) {
          mpp.pause();
          mpp.seekTo(0);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this is wrong you are not calling prepare() method on your mediaplayer before you call start() method.

Comment: on MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.red); method its automatically invoked prepare